# Como saber se uma variável é do tipo Número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, tipagem

No javascript, pelo fato de não haver declaração dos tipos de variáveis como `Integer`, `String`, `Boolean`,  etc., é uma tarefa difícil saber com qual tipo de valor você está lidando em determinada variável.

Por isso, para tornar meu código consistente, gostaria de saber como proceder para checar se uma variável é um **Numeral** ou não.

Como isto é possível?

Comment: Talvez você ache o [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) interessante.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

É simples saber se uma variável é `Numero` ou não pois há um operador nativo do Javascript que diz o tipo de sua variável, que seria o operador `typeof`, há alguns tipos de variáveis Javascript conhecidos:

```js
typeof 0;    //number
typeof 1;    //number
typeof 0.5;  //number

typeof '1';  //string
typeof 'a';  //string
typeof " ";  //string

typeof true; //boolean
typeof false;//boolean

typeof [1,2]         //object
typeof {"obj":[2,3]} //object
typeof {"obj":"3"}   //object

typeof function(){alert('foo')} //function

typeof a    //undefined -- note que nao declarei a
typeof null //null é um object(wtf)
```

Por isso aqui está um exemplo de uma função que verifica se o tipo é `number`

```js
function isNumber(val){
  return typeof val === "number"
}
```

Testando todos os valores que exemplifiquei acima, verá que apenas os com tipo `number` que comentei irá retornar `true`.

Também podemos modificar `"number"` por outro tipo para criar uma função que verifica se é `string` por exemplo, ou se é `boolean`, é simples assim.

De fato, é uma desvantagem, dependendo do ponto de vista, no Javascript não ser necessário declarar o tipo e a variável antes de usa-la.

Comment: Esclarecimento: o `typeof` não é uma função, é um operador. Você pode simplesmente usar `typeof 1`, sem os parênteses. Quando você usa os parênteses na verdade está criando uma *expression*, e a coisa toda é interpretada assim: `typeof(1)` > `typeof` e `(1)`> `typeof` e `1` > `typeof 1`.

Comment: Não entendi @bfavaretto poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: É um operador *unário* (que pede um único argumento), assim como `++`, `!`, `delete`, entre outros. Não é uma função, então não precisa de parênteses, não é uma invocação. Funciona com parênteses porque o `(1)` é processado primeiro, como expressão, entendido como `1`, e aí sim passado ao operador.

Comment: +1 lendo novamente a pergunta, concordo que sua resposta esteja mais direcionada a pergunta, só não apago a minha resposta pois pode servir como informativo para casos similares ao da pergunta que não exijam exatamente a tipagem.

Comment: Ah, e uma pegadinha, de que me lembrei vendo a resposta do Anthony Acciolly: `typeof NaN === "number"`.

Comment: agora entendi @bfavaretto - e sobre a pegadinha, bá cara javascript sempre tem um jeito de não dar certo né? kkk

Answer (score 11):

Caso não esteja buscando por verificar se algo **é** um número, mas sim se se comporta **como se fosse**, pode usar essa função:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

A ideia é que `"1"` é, para todos os efeitos, um número. Afinal você pode escrever `"1"+2`.

<sub>Baseado em uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/517503) do SO por [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms).</sub>

Comment: Essa era a implementação usada pelo jQuery até [esse commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/68213f20bb5d5426f99bafde028ecab601a9d105) que introduziu a seguinte estratégia `return n - parseFloat(n) >= 0;`

Answer (score 10):

Bom, o Paulo Roberto postou a resposta correta - e aquilo que ele certamente tinha em mente quando elaborou a pergunta - para descobrir se uma variável "contém" um número. 
Algumas das outras respostas tentaram ir pelo caminho de descobrir se uma determinada variável "representa" um número; um problema bastante comum, e uma tarefa que pode não ser tão fácil assim em JavaScript (como em boa parte das linguagens dinâmicas).

Enquanto eu talvez esteja extrapolando a pergunta, uma vez que o Paulo não mencionou esse ponto ou marcou bibliotecas na pergunta. Acho justo apontar que o famigerado [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) possui a função [jQuery.isNumeric()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) própria para resolver esse segundo problema de tipos que podem se comportar como (ou serem convertidos para) números. Na dúvida, entre escrever expressões regulares ou combinações de métodos `isXXX`, acredito que valha a pena utilizar a biblioteca, evitando assim as várias pegadinhas da linguagem:

### **Exemplos da documentação:**

```js
$.isNumeric( "-10" );     // true
$.isNumeric( 16 );        // true
$.isNumeric( 0xFF );      // true
$.isNumeric( "0xFF" );    // true
$.isNumeric( "8e5" );     // true (exponential notation string)
$.isNumeric( 3.1415 );    // true
$.isNumeric( +10 );       // true
$.isNumeric( 0144 );      // true (octal integer literal)
$.isNumeric( "" );        // false
$.isNumeric({});          // false (empty object)
$.isNumeric( NaN );       // false
$.isNumeric( null );      // false
$.isNumeric( true );      // false
$.isNumeric( Infinity );  // false
$.isNumeric( undefined ); // false
```

Comment: Dentro do tópico de tipos de variáveis em linguagens dinâmicas como JavaScript, recomendo o vídeo [**Wat**](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) [(link)](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) para quem quiser dar boas risadas (a parte do `NaNNaNNaNNaN`é especialmente engraçada).

Answer (score 9):

Javascript tem uma função nativa para verificar se não é numérico testando a junto da tipagem fraca `isNaN`.

Então se você quer saber se é numérico pode usar `!isNaN` e ele vai retornar verdadeiro pra qualquer valor numérico independente da tipagem.

Exemplo:

```
!isNaN(1); // true
!isNaN('1'); // true
!isNaN('0'); // true
!isNaN(''); // true (no caso é considerado zero pelo Javascript)
!isNaN(false); // true (no caso é considerado zero pelo Javascript)
!isNaN(true); // true (no caso é considerado um pelo Javascript)

!isNaN('texto'); // false
!isNaN({}); // false
```

Exemplo de uso condicional:

```
var numero = '12345';
if (!isNaN(numero)) {
    // se é um numero vai cari aqui
}
```

Que é uma forma compacta de escrever isso:

```
if (!isNaN(numero) === true) {
    // se é um numero vai cari aqui
}

// ou (repare que eu removi a negação antes da função)

if (isNaN(numero) === false) {
    // se é um numero vai cari aqui
}
```

Para não incluir o valor `Infinity` que é nativo e pode ser representado por uma string, você pode combinar com a função `isFinite`, exemplo:

```
!isNaN(numero) && isFinite(numero); // Se for número e não for Infinity vai retornar true
```

Comment: Não entendi, porque `1 === isNaN` retorna `false`? me explique melhor como funciona

Comment: `isNaN` é uma função, use `!isNaN(1) === true`

Comment: ahh sim, claro claro, boa sacada, realmente não sabia que esta função existia no Javascript, porém eu já conhecia o `NaN` que seria se não me engano `Not Assigned Number` que tal você incrementar sua resposta com a explicação de `NaN` ? eu poderia marca-la como correta, pois foi melhor que a minha :)

Comment: Lembrando que `!isNaN('Infinity')` -> `true`

Comment: Como assim `Infinity`? também não sabia disso, aiai javascript...

Comment: `isNaN` no javascript significa: is not a number (não é um número)

Comment: Lembrando que `isNaN` vai retornar verdadeiro para strings que podem ser convertidas para números ;) i.e.: `isNaN("0.5")` resulta em falso. Mas `"0.5" === 0.5` não é verdadeiro.

Comment: é verdade @Renan porem se for ver pelo ponto de vista da pergunta, que é sobre como saber se a variavel é do `Tipo` numero em javascript, seria correto não utilizar `isNan` não seria?

Comment: Se quiser apenas checar a tipagem da variável tem que ser com `typeof` mesmo. O `isNaN` é pra checar se não é um número para o javascript, independente do tipo.

Comment: @Renan `isNaN('0.5')` retorna falso porque `Number('0.5') === 0.5` é verdadeiro ou `+ '0.5' === 0.5`

Answer (score 6):

Eu uso a função **isNaN**, que verifica se a variável não é um número e nego ela.

```
var valor = 1.5;
var teste = "a";

console.log(!isNaN(valor)); /* retorna false negando fica true, 1.5 é tipo numérico */
console.log(!isNaN(teste)); /* retorna true negando fica falso, "a" não é um número */
```

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/66ztdbe6(v=vs.94).aspx

#### UPDATE

Você também pode converter:

```
var valor = 1.5;
var teste = "a";
console.log(!!+valor); // é um número
console.log(!!+teste); // não é numero
```

O operador + na frente da variável tenta converter a variável pra número. Caso não dê ele retorna NaN (false), negando duas vezes para obter o resultado correto: false (não é número).

Comment: infelizmente já postaram uma reposta sobre `isNaN` mas vou te dar +1 pelo esforço, obrigado! :)

Comment: Na verdade quando postaram eu estava acabando de digitar! Não faz mal estamos aqui pra aprender, o importante é que você entendeu como funciona!

Comment: @PauloRoberto todas as respostas corretas devem receber +1. Aqui não é a série Highlander.

Comment: @Laerte só lembando que `isNaN` considera strings que possam ser transformadas em números como números em si. Por exemplo, `"0.5"` é diferente de `0.5`, mas `isNaN("0.5")` resulta em falso.

Comment: mas é claro que sim, porque achas que dei +1 para ele. foi pelo esforço e por estar correta :}

Answer (score 4):

A função abaixo testa com expressão regular a string passada como parâmetro e retorna true em caso positivo (string é um número) ou false.

```
function isNumeric(str) {  
     var er = /^[0-9]+$/;  
     return (er.test(str));
}
```

fonte: http://odesenvolvedor.andafter.org/publicacoes/verifica-se-string-numro-no-javascript.html

Comment: Interessante, `Regex` é a melhor coisa que já vi na vida, da de se fazer tudo com ele.

Comment: Não é meio que uma bala de canhão pra matar uma mosca?

Answer (score 3):

Você se refere a verificar o tipo do valor ou apenas se é numérico?

Caso queira saber se é numérico você pode verificar com uma expressão regular.

O caso abaixo aceita o formato "float" assim por dizer, mas pode ser facilmente adaptado para inteiros ou para virgula ao envés de ponto:

```
function isNumeric(value) {

    return /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);

}
```