# Cálculo simples entre string e inteiro

Tags: javascript, matemática

Como impedir que isso aconteça?

```
asd = "10"

novo=asd/2;

console.log(novo) // e ele me retorna 5
```

Sendo que `asd` é uma *string* e não pode ser dívida e tratada como inteiro.

Comment: penso que a única forma é verificares se é inteiro, e se não for não fazes a divisão.

Comment: O fato de isso acontecer é básico javascript não é fortemente tipado

Comment: Para compreender a alma do JavaScript é preciso ver [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). Depois disso, a perspectiva do universo muda o_0

Comment: Como a resposta do Guilherme Bernal mostra, o JavaScript foi pensado para permitir isso. Qual resultado você queria ter? `NaN`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É uma característica da linguagem, JavaScript é **weakly typed**.

Você pode checar o tipo de suas variáveis é realmente um número antes de proceder, se quiser:

```
if (typeof(asd) == "number")
    novo = asd / 2;
else
    throw "Tipo inválido";
```

Mais detalhes sobre essa checagem: [Como saber se uma variável é do tipo Número em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4095/como-saber-se-uma-variavel-e-do-tipo-numero-em-javascript/)

Mas isso vai contra o "espírito" do js. Se você criar uma função que trabalha com um argumento númérico, um usuário pode naturalmente esperar que se ele passar uma string, vai funcionar.

Comment: Interessante seu código.. para que ser esse `throw` ?

Comment: O `throw` é parecido com um `return`. Ele aborta a função com um erro (pode ser um `new Error()`). A diferença é que não retorna para quem chamou a função, mas para algum level acima que esteja esperando por uma exceção (`catch`). Se não houver ninguém assim, tudo é abortado e o browser mostra o erro no console.

Comment: Detalhe: `typeof` é um operador e não uma função, portanto os parênteses são desnecessários – i.e., você poderia usar `if(typeof asd == "number")`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pus os parênteses por estar em dúvida sobre a precedência com o `==`. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Pode sempre verificar se a variável é um número inteiro antes de fazer a divisão.
Deixo aqui um Jsfiddle com o exemplo:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/XC4Xj/2/)

O que estou a fazer é:

1- Tenho uma expressão regular que define números inteiros

```
var verifyInt = /\d+/g; // Expressão regular
```

2- E com o `match` verifico se é inteiro ou não

```
if (asd.match(verifyInt) != null)
```