# Verificar se string possui apenas números

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual comando eu posso usar para saber se dentro de uma string só possui números..

Por exemplo, estou usando o `prompt`:

```
var quantidade=prompt('Quantidade de entrada de produtos(somente números)');
```

Gostaria de verificar se realmente na variável `quantidade` possui apenas números, afinal não podemos confiar nesses usuários não é rs.

Comment: [Questão relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4095/como-saber-se-uma-variavel-e-do-tipo-numero-em-javascript).

Comment: Por isso eu disse "relacionada" e não "duplicada". Ocorre que várias respostas daquela pergunta servem para esta, inclusive várias respostas desta são iguais as de lá.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Opção 1 (somente Javascript):

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

isNumber('123'); // true
isNumber('asda123'); // false
```

### Opção 2 (usando jQuery):

```
$.isNumeric('123'); // true
$.isNumeric('asdasd123'); // false
```

Como curiosidade, aqui vai a implementação do isNumeric no jQuery 1.11.0:

```
isNumeric: function( obj ) {
    // parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")
    // ...but misinterprets leading-number strings, particularly hex literals ("0x...")
    // subtraction forces infinities to NaN
    return obj - parseFloat( obj ) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que o downvote?

Answer (score 4):

Utilize isNaN para saber se a string contém somente números, se for falso significa que é um número:

```
if(!isNaN(num)) alert("a variavel num é numérica");

isNaN(123)         // false, então é numerico
isNaN('123')       // false então só contém numeros
isNaN('teste')     // verdadeiro, não contém números
isNaN('999teste')  // vardadeiro, contém números e letras
```

Comment: Na verdade, o `inNaN` verifica se o valor é um número. No caso, se for colocado algo como **1.23** ou **3-2**, ele retornará *true*. O que não parece ser o caso, uma vez que ele quer uma quantidade.

Comment: @JúlioPradera a função não verifica se é numérico, se assim fosse, isNaN(123) retornaria true e não false. O que a função faz é verificar se existem qualquer carácter além de números, no caso isNaN(123) retorna "NaN", ou seja, não há caracteres além de números.

Comment: @Felipe Faça o teste. Coloque "1.23" dentro de um `inNaN` e você verá que ele retornará false. Pois "1.23" É um numero. Mas não contem apenas números.

Comment: @JúlioPradera não estou a dizer o contrário. O exemplo resolve o problema, uma vez que exige apenas números, segundo o autor.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso lhe ajuda:

```
function isNumeric(str) {
  var er = /^[0-9]+$/;
  return (er.test(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode testar o String com uma expressão regular:

```
/^\d+$/.test('0'); // Retorna true.
```

Sendo que `'0'` é o numero recebido no String.

Caso queira aceitar numeros quebrados ela pode ser assim:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test('0.1'); // Retorna true.
```

Você também pode criar uma função para reaproveitar assim:

```
var

    isNumeric = function(value) {

        return /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);

    };

String.prototype.isNumeric = function() {

    return isNumeric(this);

};
```

Assim você pode usar ela dessas duas formas:

```
isNumeric('0'); // Retorna true.
```

E:

```
'0.1'.isNumeric(); // Retorna true.
```

Com jQuery já exiate uma função (`jQuery.fn.isNumeric`):

```
$.isNumeric('0');
```