# Problema ao validar se é ou não um número

Tags: javascript

```js
function isNumber(n){
 if(typeof n == "number"){
  return true
 } else{
  return false
 }
}









function contador(){
 let numero = document.getElementById('num')
 let num = Number(numero.value)
 let vet = []

 if(isNumber(num)){
  alert('É número!!!')
 } else{
  alert('Não é numero ou não foi digitado um numero')
 }
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #D96E48;
}
header{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
section{
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0.363);
}
footer{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}

#box{
    margin: 0 0 0 125px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Contador</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Cabeçalho -->
        <header>
            <h1>Contador</h1>
        </header>

        <!-- Conteúdo Principal -->
        <section>
            <div>
                <p>Digite um numero (1 a 100):
                    <input type="number" name="num" id="num">
                    <input type="button" value="resultado" onclick="contador()">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select name="box" id="box" size="10"></select>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Rodapé -->
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; CursoemVideo</p>
        </footer>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo. Qual o problema exatamente? Qual o erro que dá? Dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para algumas dicas bem úteis sobre formulação de pergunta. :D

Comment: `if(isNumber(n))` - neste trecho, não há uma variável `n` definida, tente trocar por `if(isNumber(num))`

Comment: Olá , peço que dê uma olhada em um post anterior https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11275/verificar-se-string-possui-apenas-n%C3%BAmeros, nesse link explica como utilizar o isNaN para saber se a string contém somente números.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Utilize o método [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

---

Você está tentando usar o construtor [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) em conjunto com [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para fazer a validação de um número. No entanto, essa abordagem não funciona, já que:

- O construtor `Number` retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) quando o valor passado não é numérico.
- `typeof NaN` é `number`.

Logo, passando um número ou algo que não seja número, a validação não funcionará em virtude do mau uso do operador `typeof`.

Veja:

```js
console.log(typeof NaN);
console.log(typeof Number(5));
console.log(typeof Number('Luiz'));
```

Tendo isso em vista, ao invés de usar o operador `typeof`, prefira utilizar o método [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) para realizar a verificação:

```js
function isNumber(val) {
  return !Number.isNaN(Number(val));
}

console.log(5, isNumber(5));
console.log(NaN, isNumber(NaN));
console.log('4', isNumber('4'));
console.log('Luiz', isNumber('Luiz'));
```