# Ajuda Script JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, eu comecei na programação há pouco tempo, e eu estava codando um código só pra treinar. Só que eu já procurei na internet mas eu não acho o que eu estou precisando. Vamos ao código:

```
var nome = prompt("Digita teu nome aí")

function verificaNome() {
  if (nome.length == 0) {
    alert('Tu não escreveu nada')
  } else {
    alert(`Esse nome tem ${nome.length} caracteres`)
  }
}
function verificaNumero() {
  if(typeof nome === 'number'){
    alert('Isso é um número.')
  }else{
    alert(`Esse nome tem ${nome.length} caracteres`)
  }
}
verificaNumero()
verificaNome()
```

Eu já tentei criar uma variável como "var numero = 1" pra indicar que aquela váriavel é do tipo número, mas não deu certo. O que fez mais sentido foi verificar se o tipo do nome fosse igual a number, mas também não deu certo. Queria que alguem me ajudasse.

A minha dúvida é: Como que eu indico que uma certa variável é um número? Antigamente fiz um curso de Java e lá tinha o prefixo int, que indicava que aquela variável é inteira.

Comment: `typeof` verifica o tipo da variável, e como `prompt` sempre retorna uma string, o tipo nunca será `number`. O que vc provavelmente quer ver é se **o conteúdo desta string representa um número**, e aí a verificação deve ser outra. No [link indicado acima no box azul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4095/112052) tem respostas para ambas as opções

Comment: Veja neste artigo meios de como checar o tipo da variavel:

https://stackabuse.com/javascript-check-if-variable-is-a-number/

Answer (score 0):

Para checar o tipo de uma variável é voce pode usar o typeof *variable*.
Exatamente como fez. o seu problema não é na checagem da variável. É no retorno do método Prompt, que te retorna uma String.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Technical Details
Return Value:   A String. If the user clicks "OK", the input value is returned. If the user clicks "cancel", null is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.